# ARIMA Model Prediction shows straight line

Tags: python, prediction, forecasting, arima, sarimax

I'm trying forecast RH values using ARIMA model.  Using the below code:

```
#from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import statsmodels.api as sm
model=sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(train['obs_val'],order=(3,1,3))
model=model.fit()
model.summary()
```

```
start=len(train)
end=len(train)+len(test)-1
pred1=model.predict(start=start,end=end,typ='levels').rename('ARIMA Predictions')
print(pred1)
pred1.index=df.index[start:end+1]
print(pred1)
```

Yet, when I try to forecast the values of the same date range, it doesn't quite tally up with the given values. Refer the diagram.

[image]

In addition to that, I tried forecasting values 1 year ahead and it shows up like this which seems quite inaccurate:

[image]

What is the prevailing issue here and how to get is solved? Is there a way to check the accuracy of my ARIMA model if so?

Comment: I think your `predict` call is trying to forecast `len(test)` steps ahead, so about 28 steps, according to your plot. It seems to be quite a long forecast horizon, so the forecast basically converges to the average and thus ends up being a straight line. I don't think there's anything wrong with this.